# Orthogonality in Gaussian Subspace Implies Probability Independence

Tags: probability-theory

This is an exercise from Stein and Shakarchi's *Functional Analysis*.

> Consider the space $L^2(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^d)$ of square-integrable $\mathbb{R}^d$-valued functions on the probability space $(\Omega, P)$. A closed subspace $\mathcal{G}$ of this space is called a Gaussian subspace if it is spanned by a sequence $\{ f_n \}$ of mutually independent functions, each having a Gaussian distribution measure with mean zero, and covariance $\{ σ_n^2 I \}$.
>
> Prove that if $F_1 , F_2 , \dots , F_k$ are mutually orthogonal elements of $\mathcal{G}$, then they are mutually independent.

It is not difficult to prove the case when $\mathcal{G}$ is finite-dimensional, and $\mathcal{G}$ is spanned by $f_1, \dots , f_N$, by treating $f = (f_1, \dots , f_N)$ as a $\mathbb{R}^{dN}$-valued function, which is itself a Gaussian distribution with a $dN$-by-$dN$ block-diagonal covariance matrix.

But how can I extend it to the case when $\mathcal{G}$ is infinite-dimensional?

Comment: Nonzero pairwise orthogonal vectors are always linearly independent. Consider a linear combination equal to $0$, and take the inner product with each of the vectors to conclude the coefficients are all zero.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I should have been more specific. Here by "independence", I did not mean "linear independence", but "being probabilistically independent". In this case it means if $A_1 \in \mathcal{A}_1$ and $A_2 \in \mathcal{A}_2$, $m(A_1 \cap A_2) = m(A_1) m(A_2)$, where $\mathcal{A}_1$ and $\mathcal{A}_2$ are algebras generated by $f_1$ and $f_2$ respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Even if $\mathcal G$ is infinite-dimensional, the proof should remain the same. Suppose $F_1,\dots,F_k\in\mathcal G$ are elements of the Gaussian subspace, meaning there exists a finite collection $(f_{i,j})\subset (f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ such that $$F_i=\sum_{j=1}^{n_i} a_j f_{i,j}.$$

Then you can apply the same arguments as in the finite-dimensional case to the finite-dimensional sub-subspace $\text{span}(f_{i,j})_{i,j}=\text{span}(F_1,\dots,F_k)=:\widetilde{\mathcal G}\subset \mathcal G \subset L_2$.

Comment: In general the $F_i$ can be infinite sums, no? $\mathcal G$ is the [closed linear span](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span#Closed_linear_span_(functional_analysis)) of the $f_n$.